# Python Closure not working on online interpreter

Tags: python, closures

The closure given below is working on Jupyter notebooks but displays nothing on online interpreters. Why does this happen?

```
def averager():
    nos = []
    def add(number):
        nos.append(number)
        total = sum(nos)
        ct = len(nos)
        return total/ct
    return add

a = averager()

print(a(10))
```

[image: Jupyter O/P]

[image: Online interpreter O/P]

Comment: It works at ideone.com: https://ideone.com/vjfX44

Comment: It is not running at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter  and https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: It works for me at the first one. When I try the second I get an error saying a module isn't available, but your code doesn't use any modules.

Comment: Your code is fine.